# не работает align-items: center

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, flexbox

[image: не работает align-items: center;]

```css
.reviews {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-around;
}
.reviews__list {
 text-align: center;
}
.reviews__text {
 width: 358px;
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #9a9a9a;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 31px auto;

}
.name-surname {
 position: relative;
 color: #000;
 font-size: 15px;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
}
.name__surname_img {
 position: absolute;
 left: 29%;
}
```

```html
<section class="section-seven" id="section-seven">
        <div class="container">
            <h2 class="services" id="services">
                Отзывы
            </h2>
            <div class="reviews">
                <div class="reviews__list">
                    <img src="img/reviews1.png" alt="reviews-pic" class="reviews-pic">
                    <div class="reviews__text">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur elit, eiusmod tempor incididunt labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut minim veniam, ullamco commodo consequat.
                    </div>
                    <div class="name-surname">
                        <img src="img/commas2.png" alt="" class="name__surname_img">
                        Имя Фамилия
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="reviews__list">
                    <img src="img/reviews2.png" alt="reviews-pic" class="reviews-pic">
                    <div class="reviews__text">
                        Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.
                    </div>
                    <div class="name-surname">
                        <img src="img/commas.png" alt="" class="name__surname_img">
                        Имя Фамилия
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="reviews__list">
                    <img src="img/reviews3.png" alt="reviews-pic" class="reviews-pic">
                    <div class="reviews__text">
                        Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa officia deserunt mollit anim est laborum.
                    </div>
                    <div class="name-surname">
                        <img src="img/commas.png" alt="" class="name__surname_img">
                        Имя Фамилия
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Сделал по вашему примеру. Outline сделал что бы видно было границы блоков.

```css
.reviews {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  outline: 1px solid black;
}

.reviews__list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  outline: 1px solid black;
}

.reviews__text {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #9a9a9a;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 31px auto;
  outline: 1px solid black;
}

.name-surname {
  position: relative;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 15px;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.name__surname_img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 29%;
}
```

```html
<section class="section-seven" id="section-seven">
  <div class="container">
    <h2 class="services" id="services">
      Отзывы
    </h2>
    <div class="reviews">
      <div class="reviews__list">
        <img src="img/reviews1.png" alt="reviews-pic" class="reviews-pic">
        <div class="reviews__text">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur elit, eiusmod tempor incididunt labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut minim veniam, ullamco commodo consequat.
        </div>
        <div class="name-surname">
          <img src="img/commas2.png" alt="" class="name__surname_img"> Имя Фамилия
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="reviews__list">
        <img src="img/reviews2.png" alt="reviews-pic" class="reviews-pic">
        <div class="reviews__text">
          Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.
        </div>
        <div class="name-surname">
          <img src="img/commas.png" alt="" class="name__surname_img"> Имя Фамилия
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="reviews__list">
        <img src="img/reviews3.png" alt="reviews-pic" class="reviews-pic">
        <div class="reviews__text">
          Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa officia deserunt mollit anim est laborum.
        </div>
        <div class="name-surname">
          <img src="img/commas.png" alt="" class="name__surname_img"> Имя Фамилия
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Обычно подобные блоки делают одинаковыми по ширине, а так решение вполне рабочее.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы выровнять `.name-surname` внутри флекс-элементов, нужно задать последним `display:flex;flex-direction:column` и прижать `.name-surname` к низу автоматическим `margin`

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
body{
  margin:0;
}
img{
  max-width:100%;
}
.reviews {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.review{
  text-align: center;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items:center;
  width:250px;
  flex:0 1 auto;
}

.review__text {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #9a9a9a;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 31px auto;
}

.name-surname {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top:auto;
  display:flex;
  align-items:baseline;
}

.name-surname__img {
}
```

```html
<section class="section-seven" id="section-seven">
  <div class="container">
    <h2 class="services" id="services">
      Отзывы
    </h2>
    <div class="reviews">
      <div class="review reviews__item">
        <img src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/17241-200.png" alt="reviews-pic" class="review__pic">
        <div class="review__text">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur elit, eiusmod tempor incididunt labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut minim veniam, ullamco commodo consequat.
        </div>
        <div class="name-surname">
          <img src="img/commas2.png" alt="" class="name-surname__img"> Имя Фамилия
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="review reviews__item">
        <img src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/17241-200.png" alt="reviews-pic" class="review__pic">
        <div class="review__text">
          Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.
        </div>
        <div class="name-surname">
          <img src="img/commas.png" alt="" class="name-surname__img"> Имя Фамилия
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="review reviews__item">
        <img src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/17241-200.png" alt="reviews-pic" class="review__pic">
        <div class="review__text">
          Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa officia deserunt mollit anim est laborum.
        </div>
        <div class="name-surname">
          <img src="img/commas.png" alt="" class="name-surname__img"> Имя Фамилия
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```